# Using JavaScript how do I get the padding/margin settings to always retrieve the CSS set % and not px size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

For a div with css of {padding:10% 10px 20% 10px;} I need to be able to retrieve via JavaScript the padding as it is set but window.getComputedStyle(myelement).getPropertyValue('padding'); returns different results.

Firefox = "10% 10px 20% 10px"

Chromium = "59.8839**px** 10px 119.768**px** 2px"

Is there any other way to retrieve this info so it gets the % values and not the elements current state px value?

http://jsfiddle.net/o1jhbn9f/1/

```
var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(div).getPropertyValue('padding'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi friend maybe this example could help you.
In resume the function that i test get the topBottom and leftRight property style and use split to get each side and concatenate in the right way. I hope you can use it.

```js
function getPaddingCSS(selector) {
    const elementoApp = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(selector), null);
    const elementPadding = {
        topBottom: elementoApp.paddingBlock,
        topBottomList: elementoApp.paddingBlock.split(' '),
        leftRight: elementoApp.paddingInline,
        leftRightList: elementoApp.paddingInline.split(' ')
    }
    const paddingStr = `${elementPadding.topBottomList[0]} ${elementPadding.leftRightList[1]} ${elementPadding.topBottomList[1]} ${elementPadding.leftRightList[0]}`;
    return paddingStr;
}
const selector = 'navbar';
const paddingCSS = getPaddingCSS(selector)
console.log('paddingStr of ' + selector.toUpperCase() + ':', paddingCSS)
```

```css
.navbar{
    padding: 3% 15px 30% 60px;
}
```

```html
<navbar class="navbar"> 
</navbar>
```

Comment: Hi Stalin, This works fine for a navbar or span but doesn't work for a div, h1, p tags etc. 
Any idea why it returns 0px 15px undefined 60px? Also elementoApp.padding returns 11.1354px 15px 111.396px 60px
Firefox works fine with any tag but Chromium doesn't.
https://jsfiddle.net/df804oyz/2/

Comment: Hi JayTruman, according to the mozilla documentation about [getComputedValue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) this function doesn´t give the values in format that you need, but maybe you could use this another example to get styles of the stylesheet but be careful using that:   [PaddingCSS](https://codepen.io/stalinmaza97/pen/oNopNQx?editors=0010)

Comment: Well I'd prefer if it did work the mozilla way as it would be much easier. I need to present to the user the exact values set in the CSS. I'm guessing I will have to check the styleSheets and if the tag has an overriding inline style then use that. Quite a bit more work than I thought it would be :( Thanks for your help Stalin I've certainly learnt something new 